# Windows Phone - How to refresh viewmodel when navigating back

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have two ViewModels, the first has a list of type ProductViewModel, this list of type ProductViewModel is backed by a list of type Product in my model.

```
public List<ProductViewModel> Products
{
    get
    {
        return (from product in ProductManager.Products
               select new ProductViewModel(product)).ToList();
    }
}
```

My first ViewModel will add products to the ProductManager.Products list and then raise a PropertyChanged notification so that the UI is updated. (So far so good).

A navigation to a second page then occurs, this then accesses the ProductManager.Products, once these products are processed, the ProductManager.Products list is cleared (by the second ViewModel).

**Upon navigating back to the first view, how would I then update the List Products binding?**

I am using the ViewModelLocator as provided by MVVMLight and therefore do not have static access to the first ViewModel from the second.

My current workaround is to create a BaseView page, override the OnNavigatedTo method, raise an event in this override, which I can then bind a Command to in my first ViewModel so that I can then call RaisePropertyChanged.

```
public class BaseView : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public event RoutedEventHandler NavigatedTo;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (NavigatedTo != null)
        {
            NavigatedTo(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
    }
}

    <i:EventTrigger EventName="NavigatedTo">
        <cmdextras:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=PerformNavigatedTo}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>

    public ICommand PerformNavigatedTo
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Products);
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SecondaryPageName);
                },
                () => true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you still have a question, or is your problem solved? You could have a Refresh method on your VM that is called from your first page OnNavigatedTo method, rather than using event triggers and such. Simpler approach

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my workaround above, I previously investigated implementing messaging between ViewModels. Unfortunately this wasn't working for me as I had forgotten to include the Token when calling the Register method. As soon as I sorted this out I was able to send a message from the second ViewModel to be received by the first and therefore call the RaisePropertyChanged method as required.

Also, as soon as I realised that SimpleIoC returned the same instance after multiple calls to GetInstance, this helped in my understanding.